# Can I add a 3rd monitor by using the The USBExternal Video Card?

Tags: usb, graphics-card, display, port, vga

I have a Dell Slim Studio 540S desktop computer with 2 monitors connected already. Can I add a 3rd monitor by using the [The USB 2.0 External Video Card from Iogear](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=The%20USB%202.0%20External%20Video%20Card%20from%20Iogear&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1440&bih=775&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14664077180529617922&sa=X&ei=DUJ1Tqz8HeiPsALS3tSLBQ&ved=0CHQQ8wIwAA)?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, assuming you can find drivers for your operating system (not that I'm saying that it's necessarily hard or anything...).

Comment: Is that going to be an extension of the first 2 monitors or a duplicate?

Comment: Dont expect to play games or anything on the USB video adapter.  USB 2 is fairly slow for video usage.  Its fine for web page viewing and things of that type.  Video and games that require fast updates will be laggy.

Comment: @user51210: Whatever you tell your OS to configure it as.

Comment: Excuse me, will the USB External Video Card disable the onboard video card?

Comment: It shouldn't, but again, that's up to your OS.

Comment: My Operating System is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Vista uses [WDDM 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model) which may have problems supporting more than one display driver, so if your USB adapter uses a WDDM driver it may conflict with your main display driver.

If it uses other kinds of display driver, it should work fine. The only way to be sure is to get the adapter and test it on your computer.